# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when loading a class from a jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, runtime, classloader

I was trying to load a class from a jar file with classLoader. Here is my code:

```
private void loadJar(String path, String className) {

    try {

        File file = new File(path);

        if (!(file.exists())) {
            log.error("JAR File not found!");
            return;
        }

        String anUrl = "jar:file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "!/";
        URL[] urls = { new URL(anUrl)};
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        System.out.println("className: "+className);
        Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);

        if (!(isNullaryConstructor(aClass))) {
            System.out.println("Non nullary Constructor detected!");
            return;
        }

        Object anInstantiation = aClass.newInstance();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I tried it in a test-workspace with a main class. And it works.

But, when I integrated it on my project. I obtained this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I am using Maven. Do I have to add something in the dependencies?

I listed the classes present in my jar file in order to verify that the className is correct with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JarFile jf = new JarFile(new File(jarPath));

    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jf.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JarEntry entry = e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    }
    jf.close();
}
```

And the name I entered was correct.

Any help, please!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The URL is probably wrong. Try `file.toURI().toURL()` instead. Or remove the `!/`; the standard Java classloader doesn't support this syntax.
2. The name of the class might be wrong. Make sure you use the fully qualified name (i.e. with package name), elements separated with `.` and no `.class` extension. For `String`, you would use `java.lang.String`